# UITableViewCell replace UIImageView with another image

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have custom UITableViewCell and UIImageView in it. I need to switch the content of the  UIImageView(replace 1.png to 2.png) after clicking on the UIImageView. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to make it a UIButton and set the background image. Then set up the action for the button to be

```
[button setBackgroundImage:2.png];
```

Comment: Thanks, It is the resolution for me.